# iOS-Parse Update row in Classes

Tags: ios

i am newbiew in Parse. I'm trying to learn the following this link. https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#objects-updating/iOS

Here is the updated code does not work and creating a new one. This is my code;

```
PFObject *testObject = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"TestObject"];
            [testObject setObject:@"oldtestobject" forKey:@"testkey"];
            [testObject save];
```

I just want to update the oldtestobject string. Get the new value of newtest.

I'm sorry for my english is bad. I hope what I'm saying.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to update a object with parse, you will first need to create a `PFQuery` to obtain the object you wish to update, then modify the data, then save the new version. Here is what the sample code may look like:

```
// Create the PFQuery
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"TestObject"];

// Retrieve the object by id
[query getObjectInBackgroundWithId:@"oldTestObjectID" block:^(PFObject *pfObject, NSError *error) {

    // Now let's update it with some new data. In this case, only cheatMode and score
    // will get sent to the cloud. playerName hasn't changed.
    [pfObject setObject:@"rowData" forKey:@"columnName"];
    [pfObject saveInBackground];
}];
```

Comment: But how do you get the ObjectID in the first place in order to perform the query?