# Update Query in Parse? To update existing Data?

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I have to update the existing data in parse. I am inserting the data and deleting previous data. Can anybody answer if there exist update query in parse.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16385987/ios-parse-update-row-in-classes?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a PFQuery Object with classname.

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"StoredObj"];

// Retrieve the object by id
[query getObjectInBackgroundWithId:@"yourObjectID" block:^(PFObject *pfObj, NSError *error) {
    // Update Here
    [pfObj setObject:@"aData" forKey:@"forColumn"];
    [pfObj saveInBackground];

}];
```

Hope this helps.. :)